# Linux alternative to MS Access

Tags: linux, debian, libreoffice, microsoft-access

As for most office ultities on Linux I’ve been fine with LibreOffice, with Writer and Base capable of replacing their MS Office equivalent.

However, LibreOffice Base can’t even come close to MS Access; it lacks way too much (most notably an attachment option). Are there any good alternatives to MS Access that runs on Linux (more specifically Debian)?

Comment: Just a quick google give a.o. http://www.kexi-project.org/

Comment: @albert Last time I searched Kexi was the obvious option. You might want to write that up as an answer.

Comment: I would have thought that MySql was the obvious answer. [here](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Microsoft+Access;MySQL)'s a comparison

Comment: @Mawg not really, MySQL is a "real database" (read: backend). OP asks for a graphical frontend I'd guess from the "office" context. And even if, I'd rather pick MariaDB's fork :)

Comment: Lolx! having never used MS Access, I had simply assumed it to be areal DB". Agree on MariaDB, on principle, although there's not a huge amount of technical difference (that affects me).  So, he's looking for something like [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/), though maybe as a Linux app, rather than browser based?

Comment: @Mawg He really is looking for Kexi. It is exactly a Linux clone of Access. I would write up an answer but I’ve never tried it.

Comment: That doesn't normally stop people around here :-) Why not? just list the features & how it helps him. It looks to me like the perfect answer (+1). Don't forget to link to http://www.kexi-project.org/

Comment: The programmer in me says "If you can handle Access and are Switching to Linux you can learn MySQL and PHP and do quick and easy CRUD apps via html forms, maybe some vuejs or similar."

Answer (score 2):

[Kexi](http://kexi-project.org/) is an obvious answer indeed; It has some nice features comparable to MS-Access (but also lacks a lot). You can easily connect to a (mysql) database and start creating an app. Maybe it suits your needs. If you mean working with files/images with 'an attachment option', Kexi does support that. 
They obviously try to be a very non-overwhelming, intuitive answer to MS-Access